# Insert text after "this" input-element with javascript?

Tags: javascript

Code:

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="
  if (event.keyCode == 13) { HERE, ECHO "OK" RIGHT AFTER THIS INPUT ELEMENT }
">
```

Is this possible to do without putting an ID or name on this element?
Or without encasing it in an identifiable div?

To clarify, this should be the result html after the event keycode is pressed:

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="
  if (event.keyCode == 13) { HERE, ECHO "OK" RIGHT AFTER THIS INPUT ELEMENT }
">OK
```

Comment: Why not use a class?

Comment: how do you mean then?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use jQuery you can do the following:

HTML

```
<input name="ok" type="text" id="showOK" />
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$("#showOK").keypress(function() {
  if (event.keyCode == 13){
     $("<p>OK</p>").insertAfter("#showOK");
  }
});
```

Without the Use of ID

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) { $('<p>OK</p>').insertAfter(this);}">
```

Comment: The OP specifically states without using an `id` attribute. You don't need jQuery to do that, either.

Answer (score 1):

Following your requirements and trying to keep your style, you can use the [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.insertAdjacentHTML) DOM Element method to add a text just after the `input` element.

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="
  if (event.keyCode == 13) { this.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', 'OK');}
">
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qdb58ato/)

Answer (score 1):

I used a mixture of answers here.
First off i had to create a new var:

> var that = this;

Or else javascript could not find "this" somehow.

Then used the jQUery method:

```
$('<span>OK</span>').insertAfter(that);
```

Resulting in:

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="
  if (event.keyCode == 13) { var that = this; $('<span>OK</span>').insertAfter(that); }
">
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first off, don't use inline-js. But to answer your question,

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="
    if (window.event.keyCode == 13) { this.outerHTML = this.outerHTML + 'Ok'; } "/>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xsafm0cv/2)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="ok(this, event)"/>
```

```
function ok(el, event) {
    var _ok = document.createElement('span');

    _ok.textContent = 'ok';

    if (event.which == 13) {
        el.parentNode.insertBefore(_ok, el.nextSibling)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="(function(event){
    var input = event.target;
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
      input.outerHTML += 'OK';
    }
  })(window.event);" />
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/ziwutolami/edit?html,output).

Comment: You don't need the `javascript:` protocol handler. Also, unfortunately this code requires the `input` to be the last element to work: http://jsbin.com/ziwutolami/2/

Comment: This is going to append the *OK* text node as the last child of the parent node. Not just after the `input` element. It will only work if the parent element only have this `input`.

Comment: Yes, I see @AmitJoki's answer is the best, so I'll update my answer to use the `outerHTML` method. Thanks for the correction. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="
if (event.keyCode == 13) { this.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createTextNode('OK'), this.nextElementSibling); }
">
```

It will add a text node (without creating any span or div) directly after the input.